# Remove parts of Range variable after specific string element

Tags: vba, range

I have a range variable (called Constr) that is based on date that looks like this

```
Type    Bound1    Bound2    Var1    Var2
X       1         2         3       4
Y       1         2         3       4
--  
Z       1         2         3       4
```

at the moment I am reading in the whole range, all 4 lines. But I am only interested in the first 2, the '--' should by my threshold.

What I tried to do so far is to loop through the range object and check for the "--" and copy everything before that into a new range object. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim my_constr_range As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In Range("Constr")
    If rngCell.Value = "--" Then
        Set my_constr_range = Range(Cells(my_constr_range) & Cells(rngCell.Value))
    End If
Next
```

Can someone tell me how to copy the data into a new range object or is there any better way of removing the entries after the double dash "--"

EDIT: Partial solution

So after playing around with VBA for a while I got to a point where I remove the correct rows and end up with a range object as I wanted, but unfortunately it removed the rows in my actual worksheet whereas I only wanted them to disappear in my range object.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
Dim Lrange As Range
Dim n As Long
Set Lrange = Range("Constr")

For n = Lrange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Lrange.Cells(n, 1).Value <> "--" Then
        Lrange.Rows(n).Delete
    ElseIf Lrange.Cells(n, 1).Value = "--" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

myitem("Constr") = Lrange.Value
```

How is VBA referencing back to the actual range on the worksheet, I would have thought it was working on the copied data in memory?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? Set my_constr_range = Range(Cells(my_constr_range) & Cells(rngCell.Value))     The value of rngCell.value is "--" ,how is that supposed to work with Cells()?

Comment: I tried to copy all the elements into a new range object up until hitting —, or as an alternative if it is easier crop everything after —

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then something like this will delete the rows you don't want.

```
rw = Range("Constr").Find(What:="--", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
lrw = Range("Constr").Rows.Count
Rows(rw & ":" & lrw).Delete
```

This will change your named range:
Set nr = Range("Constr")

' give an absolute reference:
nr.RefersTo = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$C$" & rw-1

Comment: I tried your solution, can you please give me some more information on how this works. rw is the row number where my -- is located, lrw is the rows included in my range variable, how would rows(rw : lrw) cover only the first 3 rows? Lets say rw = 100. Or maybe the real question is how do I save it back into my new range

Comment: This would delete the rows you don't want.

Comment: I have updated my question with an intermediate solution that I found but it looks like it doesn't get me a deep copy of my range and just uses the pointer and therefore deletes the content on the worksheet and not just in the copy of the object

Comment: Is "Constr" a named range?

Comment: I added to my answer, you will have to incorporate it into you macro.